# View state or Hidden Field

Tags: asp.net

I have to store eight to ten values in variables which are available even after post back.

I tried using Hidden Field but value is lost on post back. I am now using View state , but it seems it is degrading performance.

I have ten View State fields. what should I use to avoid poor performance ?

Comment: 10 Viewstate fields in the scheme of things will probably be rather negligible on performance. Are you trying to do pre-mature optimization or is there a real problem? If you want help with the Hidden Field method, you'll need to show how you implemented them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store Dictionary in **ViewState**.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> MyValues
{
    get
    {
        var value = ViewState["MyValues"] as Dictionary<string, string>;
        return value ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    set { ViewState["MyValues"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var myValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"One", "1"}, {"Two", "2"}, {"Three", "3"}
        };
        MyValues = myValues;
    }
    else
    {
        string value1 = MyValues["One"];
        string value2 = MyValues["Two"];
        string value3 = MyValues["Three"];
    }
}
```